# How to set character encoding for Groovydoc in Gradle?

Tags: gradle, groovydoc

I have Groovy code with UTF-8 encoding and need the generated Groovydoc HTML to use the same. But how do I configure this in Gradle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Groovydoc tool, and hence also Gradle's `Groovydoc` task, doesn't currently support an `encoding` option. Setting the `file.encoding` system property for the Gradle JVM should work though. You can do this via the `GRADLE_OPTS` environment variable, or by adding `systemProp.file.encoding=utf-8` to `gradle.properties`.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but it didn't work. Something changed when I did export GRADLE_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8" before gradle groovydoc, but it still could not produce a Norwegian 'Ø'. I run on Mac and gradle --version gives this:
------------------------------------------------------------
Gradle 1.2
------------------------------------------------------------

Gradle build time: Wednesday, September 12, 2012 10:46:02 AM UTC
Groovy: 1.8.6
Ant: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.8.4 compiled on May 22 2012
Ivy: 2.2.0
JVM: 1.6.0_35 (Apple Inc. 20.10-b01-428)
OS: Mac OS X 10.8.1 x86_64

Any more tips?

Comment: From what I've seen, `-Dfile.encoding` is the only chance. Unsure why it wouldn't work. I've already filed an issue to add an `encoding` option to Groovydoc.

Comment: Of course you'll have to set the `file.encoding` system property to whatever encoding you use for your source files (which might not be UTF-8). Groovydoc will use this encoding both for reading source files and for writing HTML. Not sure if it declares the encoding in the HTML.

Comment: My source files are UTF-8 for sure. I the problem is that it doesn't declare the encoding in the HTML.

Comment: You can easily verify this by setting the browser's encoding explicitly. And then you can write a little task that declares the encoding in the HTML.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Need to write that task though, but it's worth it to get my name spelled correctly :-)

Answer (score 0):

Surprisingly, this issue is still relevant after six years and a lot of Gradle versions :)

I've run into this issue when I had added Unicode characters (namely arrows) to my Groovydoc overview file and tried to assemble Groovydoc on a machine with default Windows-1251 encoding.

As of Gradle 4.10.2, one can use additional options for Groovydoc by providing its own implementation of [`AntGroovydoc`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/language-groovy/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/internal/tasks/AntGroovydoc.java) to the `groovydoc` task via its [`setAntGroovydoc`](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/language-groovy/src/main/java/org/gradle/api/tasks/javadoc/Groovydoc.java#L190) method. But as this method is considered internal, it would be a bit hacky solution. Besides, `AntGroovydoc` is clearly not designed for extension and its subclassing would require a lot of copy-paste from the original class.